# What kinds of champions should buy Maw of Malmortius?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For what champs is Maw of Malmortius a must buy item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57857/for-what-champs-is-maw-of-malmortius-a-must-buy-item)

Since the implement of Maw of Malmortius, I've noticed how drastically the survivability rate of HP stacking Melee champions improved, in specific, Olaf. Should all high HP AD carries should get this item? If so, how early in the game would you recommend it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't say that ONE item is the main for ALL the champions in that role. So **NO** I don't recommend it for ALL high HP AD.

I Would recommend it to Tryndamere and Olaf in special. but only those.

Answer (score 0):

it will definitively benefit champs like olaf tryndamere or jax but you need to still have a decent amount of survivalbility to build it like warmogs frozen mallet keep in mind most tanky top champs build tanky before they build high dmg.

Answer (score 0):

Maw of Malmortius is for more tanky DPS champs. AD carries are much frailer and can take fewer hits. If they need an MR item they should grab a banshee's Veil to gain a bit of health, MR and a shield to prevent a CC initiation that AD carries are so weak to.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on several champions and there is one thing i will say never build it on bruisers because stacking health will punish maw's passive because it works on % hp not total hp so more hp u have harder it is to use its passive build it on assassins like Talon,Tryndamere,Jax and in some situation Kog'maw...